# Trying to Add More tabs to tab panel upon clicking on a button

Tags: gwt

I would like to add more tabs to the tab panel upon receiving a reponse from a servelet.. the problem is that It only adds the last one and not the the others see part of the code below. It seems like it is only adding the last panel "Time Reports" but not the other two
Thank you

```
        btnLogin.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            public void onClick(Widget sender) {
                if(getLoginResult())
                                   {
                            HorizontalPanel temp = new HorizontalPanel();
             panel.add(temp, "Add Hours");
             panel.add(temp, "Time Sheets");
             panel.add(temp, "Time Reports");

                                    }

            }

        });

        RootPanel.get().add(panel);
      }

    private boolean getLoginResult() {
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback() {
            public void onSuccess(Object result) {

                isAuthenticated = true;

            }

            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Window.alert("Error when invoking the pageable data service :" + caught.getMessage());
                isAuthenticated = false;
            }
        };

        timesheetLoginServlet.isAuthenticated("1","rapidjava", callback);
        return isAuthenticated;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any widget to its parent only once. Change the temp to temp1, temp2 and temp3